# integral curve gerated by the vector field that is compactly supported

Tags: differential-geometry, smooth-manifolds

Let $M$ be a smooth manifold, take $X$ the smooth vector field that is compactly supported on $M$. denote $C = \text{supp(X)}$

Prove if the integral curve starting at some point inside the $C$,then it will stay in $C$.

My proof:

Let $\gamma:J\to M$ be this integral curve.Assume at some time $t_0$,let $\gamma(t_0) = \tilde{p} \in M\setminus C$.The we can construct a new integral curve $\hat{\gamma}(t) = \gamma(t+t_0)$ which is integral curve by translation lemma,with domain of the curve be $J-t_0$.

Now consider the point $\tilde{p} \in M\setminus C$,since exist a neiborhood(since $C$ is closed) such that vector field is constant zero on it(by solving the ODE),so exist one integral curve $\sigma(t) = \tilde{p}$ defined for all $t\in \Bbb{R}$.

Now by uniqueness of the ODE,we know $\sigma(t) = \gamma(t) $ for all $t\in \Bbb{R}\cap (J-t_0)$ imparticular $\sigma(-t_0) = \tilde{p} = \hat{\gamma}(-t_0) = \gamma(0) \in C$ but $\tilde{p }\in M\setminus C$ contradiction.

Is my proof correct?

Comment: Your proof looks correct at a quick skim, but it can be shortened: If $p$ is not in the support of $X$, the constant path $\sigma(t) = p$ is the unique flow line hitting $p$. Obviously this flow line does not go into $C$. Contrapositively, a flow line taking a value in $C$ does not hit $p$, and $p \in M \setminus C$ was arbitrary.

Comment: thank you,nice intuition